# There's a error changing values in array. <C++>

Tags: c++

This is Project Euler question 26.

I would like to save the abundant values in an array, assuming there are no more than `200` abundant numbers smaller than `28123`, which is the upper limit provided in the question.

This is not the complete code, but my program stops defining values at `abundantarr[200]`. Why am I seeing a limit to the values in this array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool IsitAbundant(int a);

int main()
{
     int abundantarr[200] = {0};
     int counter = 0;
     int totalsum = 0;

     for (int u = 1; u < 28123; u++)
     {
         if (IsitAbundant(u))
         {
             abundantarr[counter] = u;
             cout << abundantarr[counter] << endl;
             counter++;
         }
     }
  return 0;
}


bool IsitAbundant (int a)
{

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
        {
            sum+= i;
        }
    }

    if (sum > a)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: How certain are you that your `IsitAbundant` function performs as desired?

Comment: Program gets compiled. But it stops in a step defining new values in abundantarr[200].

Comment: It is possible that you're trying to store more than 200 values in `abundantarr`.  Add in a bounds check.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a debugger. Use it to inspect the value of `counter`.

Comment: It was boundary problem. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the description of the problem at Project Euler I see no mention of the number 200. How sure are you that this is the upper limit?

Comment: You don't need an array, just a running total.